# How to pass in name of file when using List<> to store payment records from filename

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file-io, filehelpers

I've wrote an app to iterate through a directory which contains x amount of files, and import each of them into objects within my program. I create an instance of a class for each of the files which are "payment", and the FileHelpers library reads each line of the file as a new record - into a List. If the files are "info", they are simply moved to preset directories. I am wanting to either append the name of the file to the end of the List or just include this as a variable?

I need to know the name of the file, as each of the "payments" within x amount of files are combined into one fixed width text file to load into our legacy housing management system.

**MORE INFO:
When I create the fixed width file, I need to output each of the payments within the `List<Payment>` PLUS the name of the file they came from. I am unsure of how to do this 
within FileHelpers/C# world :(**

E.G. (headers for display purposes - not required in export file)

```
PAYMENTID PAYMENTAMOUNT REFERENCE DATE FILETYPE FILENAME
011102010 000000010000 20148366 26102011 PO SHGR1234.PO
011102011 000000020000 20148367 26102011 PP SHGF6585.PP
011102012 000000030000 20148368 26102011 DD SHGI9854.DD
```

Any ideas? Below are some code snippets...

UPDATE - FileHelpers lib = http://www.filehelpers.com/

UPDATE 2 - Code used to loop through text file and get payments

```
public List<SundryPayment> getOAPayments()
        {
            FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(SundryPayment));
            res = (SundryPayment[])engine.ReadFile(getFilePath());
            foreach (SundryPayment record in res)
            {
                OAPaymentsList.Add(record);
            }
            return OAPaymentsList;
        }
```

Update 2 - Code to load files

```
public List<object> getFiles()
        {
            List<object> obj = new List<object>();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper();
                filePath = Path.GetFullPath(file).ToUpper();
                fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToUpper();
                fullFileName = Path.GetFileName(file).ToUpper();
                fileFund = fileName.Substring(0, 4).ToUpper();

                if (fileExt == ".DIR" || fileExt == ".ERR" || fileExt == ".CRF" || fileExt == ".STA")
                {
                    //Create Info File
                    InfoFile infofile = new InfoFile(filePath);
                    obj.Add(infofile);
                }
                else if (fileExt == ".PO" || fileExt == ".PP" || fileExt == ".TDC" || fileExt == ".TCC" || fileExt == ".DD" || fileExt == ".CSH" || fileExt == ".CQE"
                    || fileExt == ".PZ")
                {
                    if (fileFund == "SHGS" || fileFund == "GGEN")
                    {
                        //Create OA Payment File
                        OAPaymentFile oafile = new OAPaymentFile(filePath);
                        obj.Add(oafile);
                    }
                    else if (fileFund == "SHGF")
                    {
                        InfoFile infofile = new InfoFile(filePath);
                        obj.Add(infofile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Create AH Payment File
                        AHPaymentFile ahfile = new AHPaymentFile(filePath);
                        //Console.WriteLine("Object Created: {0}", filePath);
                        obj.Add(ahfile);
                    }
                }
            }

            return obj;


        }
```

Update 2 - (prototype) code used to create fixed width file. Need to put filename where paymetns came from into this file

```
public new void Create()
        {
            string fileToCreate = Path.Combine("\\\\san\\ict\\allpay\\test\\", "cash.txt");

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileToCreate))
            {
                foreach (Payment r in ArchousePayments)
                {
                    string archouseref = r.TenancyRef + r.SubAccount + r.CheckDigit;
                    string firstamount = r.AmountPaid.Replace(".", "");
                    string amount = firstamount.PadRight(10, 'x');
                    string transcode = "ALPY";
                    string date = r.PaymentDate.Substring(0, 2) + r.PaymentDate.Substring(3, 2) + r.PaymentDate.Substring(6, 4);
                    string siteref;
                    string comment;
                    sw.WriteLine(archouseref + amount + transcode + date + amount.Length);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share some code. Is "the FileHelpers library" some standard library or a proprietary one ?

Comment: @driis: see http://www.filehelpers.com - it's a free, open-source library to read (and write) (tab-, comma-)separated or fixed-width text files

Comment: http://www.filehelpers.com/ is the library in question. I'll share some code too

Comment: @driis code added above. Not sure what snippits to include but there you go :)

Comment: Anyone had any thoughts regarding this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one one by adding another fixed width record to the end of my `Import` class, then used this to store the filename via `Path.GetFileName()`. I could then pass this into the class as required.